# I want to create an mdf file of 2GB in SQL Server 2005.

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to create a new `.mdf` file of 2GB in SQL Server 2005.

What can I do to create 2GB file?

Comment: You just ... create it.... what is your problem? Where are you stuck? What are you trying to do ??

Answer (score 2):

Basically, just fire up your SQL Server Management Studio, go to your Object Explorer, and on the `Databases` node right-click and pick `New database...`.

In the dialog that comes up, give your new database a meaningful name, and set the initial size of the data file (the `.mdf` file) to 2048 MB (= 2 GB):

[image]

Click `OK` and you're done.